# New environment and resuming an enumerate

Tags: environments, enumerate

I use the enumitem package to resume the enumeration counter a lot via:

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
... 
\end{enumerate}
```

I wanted to speed it up slightly the typing, so I tried defining a new environment

```
\newenvironment{question}{
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}
```

I found that the counter is not resuming between multiple uses of this environment, however. Is the counter local to my new environment, or is LaTeX associating a new counter to the question environment, or is it something else?

I know I can define a macro

```
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
\begin{enumerate}[resume] 
\item #1
\end{enumerate}
}
```

But I have a feeling that is bad programming fundamentals.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I said I am using that package in my first sentence.

Comment: Oops!  I need to read more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

(It helps if you provide a test file) `enumitem` lifts the `resume` status out of one level of environment grouping but the double nesting defeats it. If you use the underlying command form then you avoid the double group.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}



\newenvironment{question}{%
\enumerate[resume]%
}
{%%
\endenumerate
}
\begin{document}

aaa
\begin{question}

\item zzz

\end{question}

aaa
\begin{question}

\item zzz

\end{question}

aaa
\begin{question}

\item zzz

\end{question}
\end{document}
```